# Is there a way to use Pyplot invert.axis as an overlay?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way/an alternative to using invert.axis if I want to plot two sets of different axised data on a plot?

For example: I am trying to add two sets of x and y coords on a plot, but for one of the sets, I want reversed.

I know I can use ax.invert_yaxis and ax.invert_xaxis() to reverse the one set, but is there a way to have reverted axis for one set, and the other the same?

I want both the outputs of these, essentially overlaying each other. I have attached two screenshots of the outputs from each

```css
#Get coordinates for shots 

#home team coords

x_coords_h = ([float((k['X'])) * 124.5 for k in data['h']])
y_coords_h = ([float((k['Y'])) * 80 for k in data['h']])
coords_h = ([(float(k['X']) * 124.5, float(k['Y']) * 80) for k in data['h']])

#away team coords
x_coords_a = ([float((k['X'])) * 124.5 for k in data['a']])
y_coords_a = ([float((k['Y'])) * 80 for k in data['a']])
coords_a = ([(float(k['X']) * 124.5, float(k['Y']) * 80) for k in data['a']])

#plot shots

#plot home shots
ax.scatter(x_coords_h, y_coords_h, c = "blue", label = 'shots')

#plot away shots
#ax.scatter(x_coords_a, y_coords_a, c = "red", label = 'shots')


plt.ylim(0, 80)
plt.xlim(0, 120)
#plt.text(95, 5, "@Jack_Nesbitt", color="#f7f7f7", fontsize=10)
#ax.invert_yaxis()
#ax.invert_xaxis()
plt.show()
```

```html
#Get coordinates for shots 

#home team coords

x_coords_h = ([float((k['X'])) * 124.5 for k in data['h']])
y_coords_h = ([float((k['Y'])) * 80 for k in data['h']])
coords_h = ([(float(k['X']) * 124.5, float(k['Y']) * 80) for k in data['h']])

#away team coords
x_coords_a = ([float((k['X'])) * 124.5 for k in data['a']])
y_coords_a = ([float((k['Y'])) * 80 for k in data['a']])
coords_a = ([(float(k['X']) * 124.5, float(k['Y']) * 80) for k in data['a']])

#plot shots

#plot home shots
#ax.scatter(x_coords_h, y_coords_h, c = "blue", label = 'shots')

#plot away shots
ax.scatter(x_coords_a, y_coords_a, c = "red", label = 'shots')


plt.ylim(0, 80)
plt.xlim(0, 120)
#plt.text(95, 5, "@Jack_Nesbitt", color="#f7f7f7", fontsize=10)
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.invert_xaxis()
plt.show()
```

Script output 1:

[image]

Script output 2:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if I can explain it well, but I think it's more efficient to flip the data and draw it into one plot instead of overlapping two plots. Football has a first half and a second half, and the direction of the PLAY changes as well. I hope you will take this as a suggestion and not an answer.

Comment: @r-beginners Thanks for the suggestion, yeah I would agree! The output would be the same I believe. Do you have any suggestions on the best way to flip the data? Thanks.

Comment: For example, if you're tracking the top-left coordinates as (0,0), I think you can draw points in the same pitch area by subtracting from the maximum value of 80 yards or the maximum value of 120 yards. Is that the answer?

Comment: @r-beginners Coords start at the bottom left, an example of one would be (117.52800189971924, 37.12000122070313), so using the subtract method wouldn't work

Comment: x=120-117.53,y=80-37.12, x=2.47,y=42.88
Since these x,y are the coordinates to be drawn on the left side of the pitch, I think they can unify and represent the direction of play.

Comment: @r-beginners What is the easiest way to do this using the example code above? Thanks!